# Min cost max flow optimization problem

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-optimization, network-flow

Let $I$ be the set of customers and let $J_i \subseteq J$ be the set of items from which customer $i \in I$ wants to buy only one, where $J$ are the items. Denote $w(i,j) \geq 0$ as the price customer $i$ is willing to pay for item $j$. Assume $|I| = |J| = n$.

I want to find an algorithm which computes the maximum number of customers that get an item at the minimum total cost. I'd like to do this using a min-cost max flow theorem. However, I cannot seem to succeed in constructing a graph for this problem where we can both minimize and maximize functions. Can anyone give a suggestion how I should make this graph?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You have a maximization and a minimization problem, but which takes precedence? Presumably you want to compute the maximum number $K$ of customers that can be satisfied, and find a way to satisfy $K$ customers at minimum total price. But isn't that just the obvious use of the min-cost-max-flow algorithm? What am I missing?

Comment: Indeed, I think that is how it should be done. But how do we construct the graph in a way that at most one item can be selected? I made a bipartite graph from $I$ to $J$. Each customer $i \in I$ has an edge if $w(i, j) \geq 0$, with cost $w(i,j)$. But I cannot find how I constrain the capacity of one unit of flow through the edges to the items. It's probably obvious but I'm quite stuck.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought you were struggling with the fact that we have to simultaneously maximize one thing and minimize another. In response to your comment: are you aware that the *cost* of an edge can be different from the *capacity*?

Comment: Yes, but the cost $$w(i,j) \leq c(i, j)$$. So I wonder what the capacity should be for each edge. We don't want a capacity of more than 1 from $j \in J$ to $t$, but it could be that the cost from some two vertices $i_1, i_2$ to some $j \in J$ are both $\frac{1}{2}$. Then this allows two customers to buy the same item?

Comment: I think the capacity of each edge should be $1$. I am not aware of a requirement that the cost should be at most the capacity... I don't think that's necessary?

Comment: Also, if you carry out an integral flow algorithm on a graph with only integral *capacities* (but possibly non-integral *costs*), then the resulting maximum flow will be integral. (At least this is true for variants of the Ford–Fulkerson algorithm. Not sure about other algorithms...)

Comment: I assumed that the capacity should be higher than the cost. I don't know why I thought this. Thank you! Then it is indeed an obvious application..

Answer (score 0):

Besides the customer and items nodes, introduce a source node $s$, sink node $t$, and $|I|+|J|=2n$ edges, each with capacity $1$ and cost $0$:

- $(s,i)$ for $i\in I$
- $(j,t)$ for $j\in J$

Answer (score 0):

OP was under the impression that the cost in a min-cost-flow problem should be at most the capacity. This is not the case. As such, the solution is a straightforward application of the min-cost-max-flow algorithm.